# blur in componentWillUpdate not firing, react.js

Tags: reactjs, blur, onblur

I remove the unnecessary code to make the code clear. The full standalone html file is as follow. When key pressed, I expect the input to lose focus, but actually it doesn't.

If I enclose blur with setTimeout(, 0), it will work. But why the original does not work?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="https://npmcdn.com/react@15.3.1/dist/react.js"></script>
    <script src="https://npmcdn.com/react-dom@15.3.1/dist/react-dom.js"></script>
    <script src="https://npmcdn.com/babel-core@5.8.38/browser.min.js"></script>
   </head>
<body>
<div id="root">

</div>
<script type="text/babel">
    class HelpBox extends React.Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {
            };
            window.addEventListener("keydown", this.keyDown.bind(this), false);
        }

        componentDidMount() {
            this.refs.searchWord.focus();
        }

        componentWillUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
            console.log('will blur', this.refs.searchWord);
            this.refs.searchWord.blur();
        }

        keyDown(e) {
            this.setState({});
        }

        render() {
            return <div>
                <input key="search" ref="searchWord" className="search" type="text"
                />
            </div>
        }
    }

    ReactDOM.render(
            <HelpBox/>,
            document.getElementById('root')
    );
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Resolved:** I touched DOM in componentWillUpdate, which is then restored by React in render(). That's what React should do LOL.

Answer (score 0):

the `keydown` event will trigger `blur` and `focus` events [as default](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/keydown). Without `setTimeout`, your `this.refs.searchWord.blur()` will be executed before the default `focus` because`this.refs.searchWord.blur()` is in stack. With `setTimeout`, your `this.refs.searchWord.blur()` will be put in queue which means your `this.refs.searchWord.blur()` will be executed after the default `focus` and other functions in stack. If you are not familiar with stack, queue and event loop, check [this video](https://youtu.be/8aGhZQkoFbQ)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But do not think you pin the correct reason for: 1. If I do not use react, blur() in keydown callback is fine. https://jsfiddle.net/oss3jfLy/

Comment: 2. I bind onFocus and onBlur on input element. They are not fired.

Comment: those events happen on DOM elements. try `$('.search').onblur` and `$('.search').onfocus` on chrome dev. You will see it trigger events.

Comment: Oh, you are right. These events triggered. The "focus" event triggered after the render() method. This is related to React.js, right?